# How to display div content of one page to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have mysql database, one index.php page and two dependable drop down list.
In database there is Alphabet category list, when i select "A" category, it shows A for Ahmad and Ali and so on. When i click on Ahmad, it shows Ahmad detail on same index.php page on selected div id="display".

I just only want to display selected Ahmad etc detail on another page in selected div id.

How can i do this, what are the different options

```
function getMsg(val){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"biographies_getdata.php",
        data:"lid="+val,
        success:function(data){
        $("#display").html(data);
    }
});
```

}

i am using ajax code, all is well okay, the detail is showing on index page sucking from biographies_getdata php coding page but i want to display these detail which showing on index page, need to display these information on different page..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. There is no visible effort shown here. You can send the ID in a URL on a redirect or use AJAX - hard to tell with so little details given

Comment: when you select ahmad then you can reload the page with some get argument to index.php. In index.php you can check this get parameter and display the contents in a div.

Answer (score 0):

You just link to the page you want using `<a>` tag

For example: `page2.php`.

Then you can pass the `ID` of Ahmad in the URL like this `<a href="page2.php?id=<admah id here>">Ahmad</a>`

Finally, using `$_GET["id"]` to get the `id` and using `PDO` or `MYSQLI` to fetch data from that `id`